# When calling multiple methods, will they add?

Tags: python

In python, if a person has the following code, will the 2 methods called automatically add? how does this work?

example:

```
def trip_cost(city,days):
return plane_ride_cost(city) + hotel_cost(days) + rental_car_cost(days)
```

Will `hotel_cost(days)` and `rental_car_cost(days)` both be added together when they are returned to `trip_cost(city,days)` ??

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? The order in which things are evaluated? Or how the `+` operator works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the return values of the methods you invoke have a defined `+` operator they will add up.

If the 3 return **numeric** types (for example: `float`, `int`): **yes**

But if 2 return **numeric** and one returns a `str`: **no**

The return values may also be **instances** of objects defined by yourself which may have a defined `+` operator (which may or may not be compatible with **numeric** types or with **strings**)

Comment: so since hotel_cost(days) and rental_cost(days) are both going to "Days", since the operator in the return line said to add, it will add them before placing them in trip_cost(days)?

Comment: In your case the 3 methods seem to return a **numeric** type (amount of geld which is probably a `float`. The final outlook (with some random numbers) after the methods have been called: return 32.5 + 12.5 + 40.0 ... which will return 85.0 (a `float`)

Answer (score 0):

Each function call [e.g. plane_ride_cost(city)] is evaluated and the results will be added together (in left to right order as +'s have equal precedence) then the overall result returned.